# How to delete duplicates when query is timing out?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table inside postgresql database that has duplicate values and want to add a constraint to prevent this, but I am not being able to delete the duplicates due to the delete query taking too long to run.
Query I am trying to run:

```
delete from table 
where id in 
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM 
           (
              SELECT id,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a.user_id, a.timestamp_utc ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
              FROM table  a
           ) t
        WHERE t.row_num > 1 
    )
```

The field timestamp_utc is already idexed, but the query never finishes running

Comment: Naively speaking your loop is running at O(n^3) since you've got a nested select inside a delete. Perhaps you could refactor the query into something with a better algorithmic runtime?

Comment: Does the inner query complete in reasonable time if you run it separate from the `DELETE`? If not, maybe an index on `(user_id, timestamp_utc)` will have some improvement over your index on only `timestamp_utc`. If so, do you have an index on `id` for the delete action to use?

Comment: The inner query itself is also slow
I am trying now to add the index on the fields, as @EdmCoff said, but it is also running slow and taking too long to create the index

Comment: What is the EXPLAIN plan for this statement?

Comment: Who is imposing this timeout upon you?  Maybe ask them to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly recommended creating index for together fields (user_id, timestamp_utc):

```
CREATE INDEX table_idx ON table USING btree (user_id, timestamp_utc);
```

I have written several different queries for you. You may need. After removing all duplicate data, you can add a unique index for these fields so that it would not be possible to add duplicates in the future. **It's not correct  - remove duplicates every time.**

Sample queries:

```
delete from table 
where id in 
(
    SELECT id
    FROM 
       (
          SELECT id,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a.user_id, a.timestamp_utc ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
          FROM table  a
       ) t
    WHERE t.row_num > 1 
);


delete from table a1
using  
(
    SELECT id
    FROM 
       (
          SELECT id,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a.user_id, a.timestamp_utc ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
          FROM table  a
       ) t
    WHERE t.row_num > 1 
) a2 
where a1.id = a2.id;


delete from table where id in (
select a.id from table a 
left join 
(
    select min(id) as id from table
    group by user_id, timestamp_utc  
    having count(*) > 1 
) b on a.id = b.id 
where b.id is null 
);


delete from table a1 
using 
(   select a.id from table a 
    left join 
    (
        select min(id) as id from table
        group by user_id, timestamp_utc  
        having count(*) > 1 
    ) b on a.id = b.id 
where b.id is null 
) b1 
where a1.id = b1.id;
```